# PHP stops loading mid-way through a file on all but one server

Tags: php

I have narrowed down the problem from my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933251/) and have discovered that the problem lies in the PHP code. On an AWS server and my local machine the page does not fully render (even when running the code using PHP CLI). However running the code on a server provided by my university allows the code to run (both in the browser and using the CLI), is there some configuration change I need to make to get the code running properly?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "OCI Test<br>";
            $tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc.xyz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(SOURCE_ROUTE = yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
            echo "<pre>$tns</pre>\n";
            $username = "xxx";
            $password = "yyy";
            $db = @oci_connect($username, $password, $tns);
            // Gets to here before stopping
            if (!$db)
            {
                $e = oci_error();
                print_r(oci_error());
                trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM manufacturer";
            $stmt = oci_parse($db, $sql);
            if(OCIExecute($stmt))
            {
                while(OCIFetchInto($stmt, $row, OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
                {
                        echo $row[0]. "-" . $row[1]."<br>";
                }
            }
            oci_free_statement($stmt);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seeing your code, if you don't have any error probably query return nothing. CLI output some error/warning?

Comment: i think clearly its the database at fault

Comment: @fusion3k The query returns something, when I run the code on a different server I get a result, however when running it on my laptop it stops at the line that I commented in the code, there is no finishing </body> or </html>

Comment: @Dagon When run on a different server it runs normally, and it is just a default Amazon RDS instance, but if there is some configuration that I am missing please let me know

Comment: I bet that if you leave `@` before `oci_connect` you will see a fatal error: undefined function oci_connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're database connection is not initializing correctly. You might benefit from a [try catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php). This stops errors from halting your code. It looks like you made the assumption that it wouldn't stop in your following conditional statement.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "OCI Test<br>";
            $tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc.xyz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(SOURCE_ROUTE = yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
            echo "<pre>$tns</pre>\n";
            $username = "xxx";
            $password = "yyy";
            try {
                $db = oci_connect($username, $password, $tns);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $e = oci_error();
                print_r($e);
                throw $e;
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM manufacturer";
            $stmt = oci_parse($db, $sql);
            if(OCIExecute($stmt))
            {
                while(OCIFetchInto($stmt, $row, OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
                {
                        echo $row[0]. "-" . $row[1]."<br>";
                }
            }
            oci_free_statement($stmt);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

After doing this the error will hopefully be much more helpful.

Comment: Doing so reveals the mistake, and @fusion3k is correct, I had assumed that oci was installed by default